# Appcelerator Titanium (Android) - how to search for all files on SD card with given file extensions and display them in an OptionDialog?

Tags: android, file, titanium, appcelerator, file-extension

I was wondering, does anyone know how I can search for all files on the SD card with given file extensions and display them in an OptionDialog?  I would like to search for all files on the sdcard with an .mp3, .m4a, .aac, .wav, .aif, or .aiff extension and display them in an OptionDialog.  Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

check if this question on Titanium Q&A is relevant to yours: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/160170/android---how-to-search-for-all-files-on-sd-card-with-given-file-extensions-and-display-them-in-an-optiondialog